# Blocking or forwarding packets as access point

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

I set up my Pi 2 as a wifi access point following this [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/preparation).

I'd like to implement a rudimentary QoS, according to the DSCP field in every packet's header. That means, blocking packets using low priority services (for connected hosts sending, e.g., emails) and forwarding packets with high priority services (for connected hosts using, e.g., VoIP).

I don't know where to start: how can I put in wait packets and then send them, or forward them if they are urgent?

Technically, I have to listen for packets on my WiFi dongle (`wlan0`), see the DSCP field of every packet and then send them through the Ethernet cable (`eth0`) or put them in wait.

I don't have a clue where to start.

**EDIT 1**: according to my professor, checking the DSCP field won't be reliable, since it is not always filled with something. So I'll just look at the address, and see what service sent packets by checking the site's address.

Comment: Have you investigated whether `iptables` is suitable for this purpose?

Comment: I read this manpage http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html, it seems full of interesting things.
Thank you, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Looks like you can match on the DSCP field.   Iptables may have a bit of an initial learning curve if you haven't used it before, but you definitely do want to if you are setting up an AP.  I found [this geekstuff tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/iptables-fundamentals/) a good introduction, and after that, there is the exhaustive, endlessly entertaining [iptables-info](http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-contents.html) site.  If you work this out, please leave an answer of your own!

Comment: The problem is: this is an universitarian project.
So, I'd like to do this using less possible existing libraries (e.g. libiptc) or frameworks...of course, if possible.

Comment: I don't think I can do this only by my own, I really need some libraries.
Yet I couldn't figure out how to put in wait low priority packets, and forward them after high priority packets.

Comment: One thing that's never blank w/ TCP/UDP packets is the port, which conventionally -- but not necessarily -- corresponds to a particular service (see `/etc/services` and the [IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) from which it is derived). In cases where some app has deviated from that, I'd say you can't take responsibility.

Comment: There may be cases where different forms of service with the same port (such as stuff delivered via HTTP) need differentiating and DSCP may help there (just a guess, I don't know).  Anyway, WRT libraries **libpcap** might be useful here, which gives you the opportunity to completely dissect all packets.

Comment: I discovered libneyfilter_queue, I'll give it a try.
DSCP after, now I have to learn how to put packets in a queue and delay them if they have low priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*libnetfilter_queue* library from netfilter project seems the way: from netfilter.org:

> libnetfilter_queue is a userspace library providing an API to packets
>   that have been queued by the kernel packet filter. It is is part of a
>   system that deprecates the old ip_queue / libipq mechanism.

I put packets in a queue with:

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD (parameters) -j NFQUEUE --queue-num x
```

and with *libnetfilter_queue* I can access to packets stored in the queue above.